# php functions and its detail

Tags: php

I am new to php and use Dreamweaver for coding.  I have a good grasp on some functions but am looking for a link / resource to get details on others.  Looking for a list of all built in methods/functions with definition and working examples.

Comment: [PHP Website](http://php.net)

Comment: Also **download** the manual. Just browsing the online version doesn't lead to proficiency.

Answer (score 6):

The [**PHP manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) is exactly what you need ;-)

There, you'll find both :

- A [**Language Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) : types, variables, operators, control statements, ...
- And the [**Function Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php), in which you'll have a full list of all available functions -- including those provided by extensions *(which might or might not be installed on your system)*

Also note that php.net accepts URLs with the following pattern :

```
http://php.net/FUNCTION_NAME
```

Which provide easy access to each function's documention.

For example, to access the documentation of the `strlen()` function, you'd use : [**http://php.net/strlen**](http://php.net/strlen)

Edit after the comment : going to [**php.net/print_r**](http://php.net/print_r), you'll find *(like for pretty much any other function)* -- *quoting a few sentences (there are more I didn't copy-paste)* :

- A quick description :

  `mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )`
- The parameters that function expects :

  `expression` : The expression to be printed

  `return` : If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter.
- Its return values :

  When the return parameter is `TRUE`, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is `TRUE`.
- Somes notes, and a changelog *(when the behavior / parameters / return values of a function have changes between versions of PHP)*
- A serie of examples.

Comment: i am explain my question again. for example one function is          print_R(); tell me a its parameter and its output detail. same like a java library we require

Comment: @Mani, dude empty your cup first.

Answer (score 1):

You can check all function in php manual.

Online
http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Offline , you need to download
http://www.php.net/download-docs.php